# Build docker image with terraform on bitbucket pipeline using kreuzwerker/docker provider

Tags: docker, terraform, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to build docker image using terraform and push it to Amazon ECR.

```
# omitted some basic setup of provider and auth
#
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "my_repo" {
  name = "my-ecr-repo"
}

resource "docker_image" "my_image" {
  name = "xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-ecr-repo:latest"
  build {
    context = "../../apps/dockertest"
  }
}

resource "docker_registry_image" "handler" {
  name = docker_image.my_image.name
}
```

and the simplest Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY myfile.txt myfile.txt
CMD ["cat", "myfile.txt"]
```

when I run *terraform apply* locally, everything works fine.
but when I run this on bitbucket pipeline, something strange happens: looks like files are not copied. in pipeline docker log I see following:

```
level=error msg="Can't add file /var/lib/docker/165536.165536/overlay2/lzpejtjd0vm6y4cmqc3ckrsw1/diff/myfile.txt to tar: Host ID 0 cannot be mapped to a container ID"
```

and during docker run there will be an error: *can't open 'myfile.txt': No such file or directory*

Looks like the paths are correct. If in Dockerfile I copy the file which doesn't exists, it will fail the process with clear error.
But in my case all steps are finished successfully, just no files added to the image and message in logs.

For now as a workaround I use null_resource, and it works fine and produce correct image:

```
resource "null_resource" "docker_packaging" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
        echo ${local.ecr_tkn} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.ecr_token.proxy_endpoint}
        docker build -t "${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:latest" -f ${var.code_path}/Dockerfile ${var.code_path}
        docker push "${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:latest"
        EOF
  }
```

Comment: I guess it depends on the repository structure. Are the Dockerfile and `myflie.txt` in the root of the repo or not?

Comment: No, it's not. int in the separate folder. but I guess the paths are correct: when I do mistake in path, it throws error that can't find dockerfile. if in dockerfile I have a wrong path, it also throws clear error.

Comment: Could you share the relevant fragments of your bitbucket-pipelines.yml?

Comment: Does a regular `docker build` instruction not triggered from a terraform provider produce the correct image in the pipeline?

Comment: regular docker build produces correct image. for now as a workaround I use null_resource, and it works fine.